# Unit testing XSLT files in pycharm

Tags: python, unit-testing, xslt, pycharm, pytest

I wrote several xslt files. Within each file, I have multiple templates to modify strings, so I am trying to find a way to create unit tests for these templates. Is there is a way to test xslt files in PyCharm with pytest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for anyone else who wants to test xslt files in python using pytest: I am using `lxml.etree` to parse the a sample XML file and the xslt file I have, then using `lxml.etree.XSLT` and `transform()` to transform the html output into an `etree` object. I can compare what I expect to be within certain tags to what is actually there based on the xslt transformation.